# Getting -1 with getColumnIndex() while retrieving a contact number - Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve a contact's number. I can access the contact name with no problems but when I try to access the contact number I get an exception because `getColumnIndex` returns -1, which means that it couldn't find the column I requested. But I can't understand why it does not find the column when from the Android docs I see that the column does exist.

Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<String> getContactById(String contactId)
    {
        Log.d("XYZ", "Contact id -> " + contactId);
        ArrayList<String> contact = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
final String[] projection = new String[] {
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,  // the name of the contact
                Contacts.PHOTO_ID       // the id of the column in the data table for the image
            };

        final Cursor curContact = cr.query(
                Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                Contacts._ID + "=?",    // filter entries on the basis of the contact id
                new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)},    // the parameter to which the contact id column is compared to
                null);

        if(curContact.moveToFirst()) {
            final String name = curContact.getString(curContact.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            final String photoId = curContact.getString(curContact.getColumnIndex(Contacts.PHOTO_ID));
                Log.d("XYZ", "Name -> " + name);
                Log.d("XYZ", "Photo id -> " + photoId);
            }



        // Get the phone numbers

        final String[] phoneNumbersProjection = new String[] {
                Phone.NUMBER,
                Phone.TYPE,
        };

        final Cursor curPhone = cr.query(
                Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null,
                //new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)},
                null);

        if(curPhone.moveToFirst()) {
            final int contactNumberColumnIndex = curPhone.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            final int contactTypeColumnIndex = curPhone.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);

            Log.d("XYZ", "contactNumberColumnIndex -> " + contactNumberColumnIndex);
            Log.d("XYZ", "contactTypeColumnIndex -> " + contactTypeColumnIndex);

            while(!curPhone.isAfterLast()) {
                final String number = curPhone.getString(contactNumberColumnIndex);
                final int type = curPhone.getInt(contactTypeColumnIndex);
                final int typeLabelResource = Phone.getTypeLabelResource(type);
                Log.d("XYZ", "Contact number -> " + number);
                //Log.d("XYZ", "Number Type -> " + typeLabelResource);
                //doSomethingWithAContactPhoneNumber(number, typeLabelResource);
                curPhone.moveToNext();
            }

        }
        curPhone.close();
        curContact.close();
        return contact;
    }
```

With:

```
Log.d("XYZ", "contactNumberColumnIndex -> " + contactNumberColumnIndex);
Log.d("XYZ", "contactTypeColumnIndex -> " + contactTypeColumnIndex);
```

I receive:

```
contactNumberColumnIndex -> -1
contactTypeColumnIndex -> -1
```

Can anyone figure out what is wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to add, I'm following this tutorial -> http://www.app-solut.com/blog/2011/03/working-with-the-contactscontract-to-query-contacts-in-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong projection:

```
final String[] phoneNumbersProjection = new String[] {
        Phone.NUMBER,
        Phone.TYPE,
};

final Cursor curPhone = cr.query(
        Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
```

You should be using `phoneNumbersProjection` and not the `projection` you used for another query earlier.

Generally, `getColumnIndex()` tries to find the column from those in the `Cursor` so if a column is not found, first check that you're including the column in the query in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! These errors kill my patience sometimes :) I should buy you a beer!

Answer (score 2):

```
 final Cursor curPhone = cr.query(
                Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                phoneNumbersProjection,
                Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null,
                //new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)},
                null);
```